# Excel e SQL - Conexão entre arquivo do Excel

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, vba

Tenho o código no (final) que peguei na internet.
Nesta linha de código dá erro no WHERE, pois é um texto:

```
strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
" FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = Murilo;"
```

Substituindo por este abaixo não dá erro no WHERE, sendo um número:

```
strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
" FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Total] >= 100000;"
```

E pergunto: precisa deste ponto e vírgula no final?

Segue o código completo, e também pergunto:
Precisa de setar Nothing no final do código para as variáveis conn, rst e fld?
Para o código completo rodar, é preciso adicionar alguma Referência?

```
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim wkCaminho, wkArquivo As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim fld As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    wkCaminho = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    wkArquivo = "MATRIZ DE DADOS.xlsx"
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Delete
    ' Hard code database location and name
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='" & wkCaminho & wkArquivo & "';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

'    strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
'    " FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Total] >= 100000;"

    strSQL = " SELECT [VENDAS$].[Data], [VENDAS$].[Vendedor], [VENDAS$].[Total]" & _
    " FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = Murilo;"

    ' Open the db connection
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' column headers
    I = 0
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, I) = fld.Name
        I = I + 1
    Next fld

    ' data rows
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close

    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa colocar aspas simples quando trata-se de caracteres, com números não precisa como você mesmo já fez o teste.
Tente colocar dessa maneira: " FROM [VENDAS$] WHERE [VENDAS$].[Vendedor] = **'Murilo'**;"

Comment: Obrigado Raphael!
E quanto à Biblioteca e setar Nothing?

Comment: Sobre vba eu ainda não conheço o suficiente pra poder ajudar